# Increase Rabbitmq heartbeat timeout with Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, fastapi

So I am using rabbitmq docker image with celery and fast API to deploy a ML model over an Ubuntu Instance using docker compose.

Everything works well, but sometimes, when the model processing takes too long, I get the
"missed heartbeat" message from rabbitmq, which makes the request rerun, and hence becomes an endless loop.

I think the best solution would be to increase the heartbeat timeout, but I don't know how to do that, especially in docker image.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank You.